# Unauthorized Error From Server when send Request to Server in Angular6

Tags: javascript, asp.net, angular, asp.net-core, angular6

i need to create a website  with angular6 and aspcore .

i create a server with asp core and it create this token :

```
{
"access_token": "eyJhbGciOiJIUzI1NiIsInR5cCI6IkpXVCJ9.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.zhW3aoRKGaoy-wEbO7RnbdQmxCXSy50pSaqO1OoEwe8",
"refresh_token": "eyJhbGciOiJIUzI1NiIsInR5cCI6IkpXVCJ9.eyJqdGkiOiJiMDEyNTQxYi0yZDljLTE2N2UtZDM0Ni1hZjNlNWRiYjMzYzgiLCJpc3MiOiJodHRwOi8vbG9jYWxob3N0OjQ0MzkwLyIsImlhdCI6MTU0NDg2OTU1OSwiaHR0cDovL3NjaGVtYXMubWljcm9zb2Z0LmNvbS93cy8yMDA4LzA2L2lkZW50aXR5L2NsYWltcy9zZXJpYWxudW1iZXIiOiIwZGMwMTRmNDc1NTQ1Y2MyYjEwNzUzZjU1YTFlOTQxNyIsIm5iZiI6MTU0NDg2OTU1OSwiZXhwIjoxNTQ0ODczMTU5LCJhdWQiOiJBbnkifQ.8vwTvDJcT8MoOfvqVb7gGzSxbll2_u91bArumJDW65k"
}
```

and this is my service for find userInfo :

```
  public UserInfo(username:string):Observable<IUser>{
return this.http.get<IUser>(`${this.baseUrl+'GetUserInfo/'}${username}`,{headers:{
  'Content-Type': 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
  'Authorization': 'Bearer ' + this.broserStorage.GetLocalStorage('AccessToken')+this.broserStorage.GetLocalStorage('RefreshToken'),
},
})
.pipe(
  tap((user: IUser) => this.log(`GetUserInfo user w/ email=${user}`)),
  catchError(this.handleError<IUser>('GetUserInfo user'))
);
```

}

i send the request but it show me this error :

> GetUserInfo user failed: Http failure response for https://localhost:44390/api/user/GetUserInfo/kia@kia.com: 401 Unauthorized

**whats problem ? From Server or Angular ?**

this code from Server :

```
[HttpGet("GetUserInfo/{username}")]
    [Authorize(AuthenticationSchemes = JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme)]
    public async Task<IActionResult> GetUSerInfo(string username)
    {
        UserRoleViewModel URVM = new UserRoleViewModel();
        var user = await _applicationUserManager.FindByNameAsync(username);
        if (user != null)
        {
            var roles = await _applicationUserManager.GetRolesAsync(user);
            var roleName = await _applicationRoleManager.FindRoleByNameList(roles[0]);
            URVM.Id = user.Id;
            URVM.Email = user.Email;
            URVM.BirthDate = user.BirthDate;
            URVM.CreatedDateTime = user.CreatedDateTime;
            URVM.FirstName = user.FirstName;
            URVM.IsActive = user.IsActive;
            URVM.PhoneNmuberConfirmed = user.PhoneNumberConfirmed;
            URVM.IsEmailPublic = user.IsEmailPublic;
            URVM.LastName = user.LastName;
            URVM.TwoFactorEnabled = user.TwoFactorEnabled;
            URVM.EmailConfirmed = user.EmailConfirmed;
            URVM.LockoutEnabled = user.LockoutEnabled;
            URVM.LastVisitDateTime = user.LastVisitDateTime;
            URVM.Location = user.Location;
            URVM.PhotoFileName = user.PhotoFileName;
            URVM.RoleLevel = roleName.RoleLevel;
            URVM.Description = roleName.Description;
            URVM.roleId = roleName.Id;
            URVM.desplayName = user.FirstName + " " + user.LastName;
            return Ok(URVM);
        }
        return BadRequest();
    }
```

this Startup :

```
services.AddCors(options =>
        {
            options.AddPolicy("CorsPolicy",
                builder => builder
                    .WithOrigins("http://localhost:4200") //Note:  The URL must be specified without a trailing slash (/).
                    .AllowAnyMethod()
                    .AllowAnyHeader()
                    .AllowCredentials());
        });
        services.AddIdentity<User, Role>().AddUserStore<ApplicationUserStore>()
            .AddUserManager<ApplicationUserManager>()
            .AddRoleStore<ApplicationRoleStore>()
            .AddRoleManager<ApplicationRoleManager>()
            .AddSignInManager<ApplicationSignInManager>()
            .AddDefaultTokenProviders();
        services
           .AddAuthentication(options =>
           {
               options.DefaultChallengeScheme = JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
               options.DefaultSignInScheme = JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
               options.DefaultAuthenticateScheme = JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
           })
           .AddJwtBearer(cfg =>
           {
               cfg.RequireHttpsMetadata = false;
               cfg.SaveToken = true;
               cfg.TokenValidationParameters = new TokenValidationParameters
               {
                   ValidIssuer = Configuration["BearerTokens:Issuer"], // site that makes the token
                   ValidateIssuer = false, // TODO: change this to avoid forwarding attacks
                   ValidAudience = Configuration["BearerTokens:Audience"], // site that consumes the token
                   ValidateAudience = false, // TODO: change this to avoid forwarding attacks
                   IssuerSigningKey = new SymmetricSecurityKey(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(Configuration["BearerTokens:Key"])),
                   ValidateIssuerSigningKey = true, // verify signature to avoid tampering
                   ValidateLifetime = true, // validate the expiration
                   ClockSkew = TimeSpan.Zero // tolerance for the expiration date
               };
               cfg.Events = new JwtBearerEvents
               {
                   OnAuthenticationFailed = context =>
                   {
                       var logger = context.HttpContext.RequestServices.GetRequiredService<ILoggerFactory>().CreateLogger(nameof(JwtBearerEvents));
                       logger.LogError("Authentication failed.", context.Exception);
                       return Task.CompletedTask;
                   },
                   OnTokenValidated = context =>
                   {
                       var tokenValidatorService = context.HttpContext.RequestServices.GetRequiredService<ITokenValidatorService>();
                       return tokenValidatorService.ValidateAsync(context);
                   },
                   OnMessageReceived = context =>
                   {
                       return Task.CompletedTask;
                   },
                   OnChallenge = context =>
                   {
                       var logger = context.HttpContext.RequestServices.GetRequiredService<ILoggerFactory>().CreateLogger(nameof(JwtBearerEvents));
                       logger.LogError("OnChallenge error", context.Error, context.ErrorDescription);
                       return Task.CompletedTask;
                   }
               };
           });
        public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IHostingEnvironment env)
    {
        app.UseExceptionHandler(appBuilder =>
        {
            appBuilder.Use(async (context, next) =>
            {
                var error = context.Features[typeof(IExceptionHandlerFeature)] as IExceptionHandlerFeature;
                if (error != null && error.Error is SecurityTokenExpiredException)
                {
                    context.Response.StatusCode = 401;
                    context.Response.ContentType = "application/json";
                    await context.Response.WriteAsync(JsonConvert.SerializeObject(new
                    {
                        State = 401,
                        Msg = "token expired"
                    }));
                }
                else if (error != null && error.Error != null)
                {
                    context.Response.StatusCode = 500;
                    context.Response.ContentType = "application/json";
                    await context.Response.WriteAsync(JsonConvert.SerializeObject(new
                    {
                        State = 500,
                        Msg = error.Error.Message
                    }));
                }
                else
                {
                    await next();
                }
            });
        });
        if (env.IsDevelopment())
        {
            app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();
        }
        else
        {
            app.UseHsts();
        }

        app.UseHttpsRedirection();
        app.UseCors("CorsPolicy");
        app.UseAuthentication();
        var scopeFactory = app.ApplicationServices.GetRequiredService<IServiceScopeFactory>();
        app.UseMvc(routes =>
        {
            routes.MapRoute(
                name: "areas",
                template: "{area:exists}/{controller=Home}/{action=Index}/{id?}"
            );
        });
    }
```

**Edit**

i add this class :

```
    @Injectable()
export class AuthInterceptorService implements HttpInterceptor  {

  private delayBetweenRetriesMs = 1000;
  private numberOfRetries = 3;
  private authorizationHeader = "Authorization";

  constructor(
    private tokenStoreService: TokenstoreService,
    private router: Router) { }

  intercept(request: HttpRequest<any>, next: HttpHandler): Observable<HttpEvent<any>> {
    const accessToken = this.tokenStoreService.getRawAuthToken(AuthTokenType.AccessToken);
    if (accessToken) {
      console.log('in if')
      request = request.clone({
        headers: request.headers.set(this.authorizationHeader, `Bearer ${accessToken}`)
      });
      return next.handle(request).pipe(
        retryWhen(errors => errors.pipe(
          mergeMap((error: HttpErrorResponse, retryAttempt: number) => {
            if (retryAttempt === this.numberOfRetries - 1) {
              console.log(`HTTP call '${request.method} ${request.url}' failed after ${this.numberOfRetries} retries.`);
              return throwError(error); // no retry
            }

            switch (error.status) {
              case 400:
              case 404:
                return throwError(error); // no retry
            }

            return of(error); // retry
          }),
          delay(this.delayBetweenRetriesMs),
          take(this.numberOfRetries)
        )),
        catchError((error: any, caught: Observable<HttpEvent<any>>) => {
          console.error({ error, caught });
          if (error.status === 401 || error.status === 403) {
            const newRequest = this.getNewAuthRequest(request);
            if (newRequest) {
              console.log("Try new AuthRequest ...");
              return next.handle(newRequest);
            }
            this.router.navigate(["/accessDenied"]);
          }
          return throwError(error);
        })
      );
    } else {
      // login page
      return next.handle(request);
    }
  }

  getNewAuthRequest(request: HttpRequest<any>): HttpRequest<any> | null {
    const newStoredToken = this.tokenStoreService.getRawAuthToken(AuthTokenType.AccessToken);
    const requestAccessTokenHeader = request.headers.get(this.authorizationHeader);
    if (!newStoredToken || !requestAccessTokenHeader) {
      console.log(" first =>There is no new AccessToken.", { requestAccessTokenHeader: requestAccessTokenHeader, newStoredToken: newStoredToken });
      return null;
    }
    const newAccessTokenHeader = `Bearer ${newStoredToken}`;
    if (requestAccessTokenHeader === newAccessTokenHeader) {
      console.log(" second =>There is no new AccessToken.", { requestAccessTokenHeader: requestAccessTokenHeader, newAccessTokenHeader: newAccessTokenHeader });
      return null;
    }
    console.log("third")
    return request.clone({ headers: request.headers.set(this.authorizationHeader, newAccessTokenHeader) });
}
}
```

and add this in appmodule :

```
    { provide: HTTP_INTERCEPTORS,useClass: AuthInterceptorService,multi: true},
```

and this request:

```
  public UserInfo(username:string):Observable<IUser>{
return this.http.get<IUser>(`${this.baseUrl+'GetUserInfo/'}${username}`,{headers:{
  'Content-Type': 'application/json; charset=utf-8'
},
})
.pipe(
  tap((user: IUser) => this.log(`GetUserInfo user w/ email=${user}`)),
  catchError(this.handleError<IUser>('GetUserInfo user'))
);
```

}

but it show me this error :

> second =>There is no new AccessToken. 
>   Object { requestAccessTokenHeader: "Bearer \"\\"eyJhbGciOiJIUzI1NiIsInR5cCI6IkpXVCJ9.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.NNKPkwayicwLo8K-K1weP7vGAkL8Cpo9Zx-xtrh6I4E\\"\"", newAccessTokenHeader: "Bearer \"\\"eyJhbGciOiJIUzI1NiIsInR5cCI6IkpXVCJ9.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.NNKPkwayicwLo8K-K1weP7vGAkL8Cpo9Zx-xtrh6I4E\\"\"" }
>   auth-interceptor.service.ts:74:6
>   Object { headers: {…}, status: 401, statusText: "Unauthorized", url: "https://localhost:44390/api/user/GetUserInfo/kia@kia.com", ok: false, name: "HttpErrorResponse", message: "Http failure response for https://localhost:44390/api/user/GetUserInfo/kia@kia.com: 401 Unauthorized", error: null }
>   user.service.ts:113:6
>   GetUserInfo user failed: Http failure response for https://localhost:44390/api/user/GetUserInfo/kia@kia.com: 401 Unauthorized

Comment: Look at your server logs. They should be able to tell you what rejected the request.

Comment: How do you run your app? Through Visual Studio? Either a console window should have opened (with lots of logs), or the logging output is visible in the Output panel when selecting the ASP.NET Core web application there.

Comment: @poke `it show this log: Microso.AspNetCore.Authentication.JwtBearer.JwtBearerHandler:Information: Bearer was not authenticated. Failure message: No SecurityTokenValidator available for token: [object Object] Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authorization.DefaultAuthorizationService:Information: Authorization failed. Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Internal.ControllerActionInvoker:Information: Authorization failed for the request at filter 'Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Authorization.AuthorizeFilter'. Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.ChallengeResult:Information: Executing ChallengeResult with authentication schemes (Bearer)`

Comment: The error message says “No SecurityTokenValidator available”. I would make sure that your JWT configuration is correct and also make sure that you are doing the right thing in those events there. If configured properly, you shouldn't have to have custom logic there.